# AWS S3 getSignedUrl() Returns Expired SignedURLs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, mean-stack

**Works fine on `localhost` but not on the Server**. All the URL s returned are already **expired**.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Request has expired</Message>
<Expires>2016-04-26T09:44:22Z</Expires><ServerTime>2016-04-26T11:34:36Z</ServerTime><RequestId>33AF4E321F37ADA6</RequestId><HostId>+AXA3itXG9aKlt+EQkYxTHJCsxkEkymj+o2COPYo4+v26Vaxx17j/agh+hCq5NoHNzvJp2GI8Y=</HostId>
</Error>
```

On `localhost`, URL s generated for the same object differs in `expires` parameter but not on the Server. Same URL is returned for the same object on Server(`expires` param is same everytime).

Server is Amazon EC2. Credentials are saved in `/.aws/credentials` file on both `localhost` and the Server

***Code from Model***

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.download = function (req, res) {

    var fileName = req.params.name;

    var key = req.user._id + '/' + fileName;

    var params = { Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: key };

    s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function (err, url) {

        if (err) {
            console.log('Getting Signed URL', err);
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Getting Signed URL', url);
            res.send(url);            
        }
    });
};
```

***Edited CORS Configuration on S3***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: The documentation says that it will default to a validity period of 15 minutes, so that result is strange. Have you tried passing an `Expires` value? See: [getSignedUrl() documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property)

Comment: I passed the `Expires` value. Same result.

Comment: Can you extract the expiration time from the resulting URL to check its value? (It would be in UTC.)

Comment: File was just uploaded. Result of URL in browser.`<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Request has expired</Message><Expires>2016-05-09T09:27:53Z</Expires><ServerTime>2016-05-09T09:28:58Z</ServerTime><RequestId>35CA4C50C6F689E3</RequestId><HostId>/OswGs5Ixdpx5+ngNyBLwgnm1PWGqm4MhcfSNHHGLWEDLDg1I+FVcOHPfcvGEwvVTt1RIIK870M=</HostId></Error>`

Comment: How about the actual Signed URL? Can you see the expiry time in the URL that is sent to S3?

Comment: https://myBucket.s3.amazonaws.com/5690e24b2897e3970650383a/google-play-en-135x40.png?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&Expires=1462786073&Signature=sm5RrFD1ZnTVafCn%2FYYiR0OoltI%3D

Comment: That URL contains `&Expires=1462786073`, which equates to `Mon, 09 May 2016 09:27:53 GMT`, which matches the error message you saw. I wonder if the time is being generated from your local computer rather than on AWS itself? Please check the time on your computer and see if it matches the 'real' time. Also, try one with `Expires: 86400` to get a full 24 hours.

Comment: Time on my computer is correct. I don't think it's a timezone problem. As I have mentioned in my question, requests from `localhost` works fine and gets new signed URLs each time I request (new `Expires` value). But on the server I get the same URL (same `Expires` value all the time).

Answer (score 1):

```
...
// here you need to provide signed URL expiration time as the 3rd parameter
var params = { Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: key , Expires: <expire time>};

s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function (err, url) {
...
```

Comment: It didn't work. Please see the comments on the question. I got it fixed somehow. Forgot to post the answer and can't remember now.

Answer (score 0):

Will probably not apply to this specific question, but I'm adding this in case anyone runs into this question like I did while trying to solve my problem. I had the same issue of expired signed URLs because I'm using WSL2 + Docker in my dev environment, and after putting my laptop to sleep the clock got messed up. The "fix" was to restart WSL2. There are other options but I didn't get the chance to test them.
There are some extra details in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4245)

Answer (score 0):

When you generate file link you will have something like

> https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/image2.png?SOME_INFO&X-Amz-Expires=900&SOME_INFO

You need *X-Amz-Expires=900*.
This parameter means count of secont when your SignedUrl will expire.

To increse time, you an use some example

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const s3 = new aws.S3({
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    region: 's3-region'
});

const s3FileObject = {
  Bucket: 'your-bucket-name',
  Key: 'file-name.jpg',
  Expires: 60 * 60 // Seconds count
};

const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', s3FileObject);

console.log(url);
```